# how will i do if i need this code of some java script, css and html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with my code; I need a counter that, when I click on the button, and when I miss I would like minus points. I am very new to coding, and I need help. Please respond if you have time.

```js
function update(e) {
  var x = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX
  var y = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY

  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorX', x + 'px')
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorY', y + 'px')
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', update)
document.addEventListener('touchmove', update)

function jump() {
  var x = Math.round((Math.random() * 101)) + "%",
    y = Math.round((Math.random() * 101)) + "%";
  document.getElementById("jump").style.left = x;
  document.getElementById("jump").style.top = y;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #21096b;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.button-container {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100vw - 100px);
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button id="jump" onclick="jump()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` in the CSS.

Comment: Use a global variable to hold the counter. Add 1 to it when the user clicks on the button, subtract 1 from it when they click outside the button. After that, display the value of the counter variable in a DIV after the click.